# can not get the correct array length

Tags: javascript

The code below returns the length of an array

```
var test=[];
test["abc"]=1;
test["abcd"]=11;
console.log(test.length);
```

I expected it outputs 2
but it displays 0

Your comment welcome

Comment: you are adding properties as explained in the answers, but why not use a JavaScript object var test = {}, and add properties to it instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should count the number of keys using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
console.log(Object.keys(test).length); // 2
```

Ideally, don't use array but a plain JavaScript object (also called *hash*):

```
var test = {};
test.abc = 1;
test.abcd = 11;
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't actually adding any elements to the array, this is creating properties on the array object.

You can tell that I am saying the truth by typing this:

```
console.log(test.abc);
console.log(test.abcd);
```

The `length` would have been increased probably if you had added the elements using `push()` or set them using a numerical index like:

```
test[0] = 1;
test[1] = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to a misunderstanding of what consitutes and array in Javascript.

In Javascript, an `array` is specified as a specific type of object, consisting of only numeric keys.

The `.length` is a special property of the array object, which is tied to the value of the largest numeric key in the array.

By using keys such as `"abc"`, you are in fact merely setting arbitrary properties on the object; the `length` property will be completely unaffected by this.

You have two options:

1. Use numeric keys for your array.
2. If you need to use named keys, you will have to accept that the `length` property and other array-specific features are not available. So you may as well use a regular object rather than an array.

   It is still possible to count the elements in an object, but it's not as simple as just using a `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add items to the array use

```
 array[0] = 1;
 array[1] = 11;
```

Otherwise you are adding properties to the array